# Почему не стоит запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вопросительный-знак

Фраза, опять-таки, из учебника:

> Определите на какую высоту поднимается вода, если давление, созданное насосом, равно 400 кПа?

Во первых, конечно же, интересно, почему не стоит запятая после *определите*, ведь она ставится между частями сложного предложения.

И почему вопросительный знак, если это побудительное предложение?

Comment: Это учебник физики? Современный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Определите (что?)**, на какую высоту поднимается вода, если давление, созданное насосом, равно 400 кПа?*

Это СПП с **изъяснительным** значением, союзное слово НА КАКУЮ.

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88)**

**Примечание.** Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения содержит косвенный вопрос, то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится: Я прервал речь Савельича вопросом, сколько у меня всего денег (П.); Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, когда он может выписаться (Н. О.).

Однако, если косвенный вопрос содержит **сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию,** в конце сложноподчиненного предложения ставится вопросительный знак: **Скажите,** пожалуйста, что это за огни? (Л. Т.); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (М. Г.)

Comment: Ошибка, да? Изначально думал, что так.

Comment: Максим,  в чем ошибка? Знак нужен при  сильно выраженной вопрос. интонации.

Comment: Про отсутствие запятой говорю, а не знак.

Comment: Да, запятая обязательно нужна.  Сравнить: Определите высоту подъема воды.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.